# Word or phrase for ‘unique phrase that a person habitually says’

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase to denote such a unique phrase that somebody habitually says. This phrase could for example fill the following gap:

> My buddy Bill always exclaims “oh wow” whenever he is surprised. “Oh wow” is a _____ of his.

Comment: I was tempted to say *swan song of his* - but a swan song is not merely an expression but a typical argument of someone. I think I would just say that it is a *favourite expression* of his.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not correct. A swan song is a last performance before an artist dies or retires. I would suggest "catchphrase".

Comment: Is this a cliche ?

Comment: @KateBunting *catchphrase* seems very close but more common when the subject is a famous person.

Comment: What about something reusing the words in question - *Oh wow” is **a habitual saying|expression|phrase** of his*

Comment: a cliché of his. Why give a fancy name to something that isn't?

Answer (score 3):

This can be a [**catchphrase**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catchphrase). I think this is most commonly applied to fictional characters, who often have very distinction catchphrases (such as Sheldon's "bazinga" on The Big Bang Theory), but it could conceivably apply to actual people if they have similar ideosyncracies.

Comment: Ay Caramba! This is the answer. (D'Oh!)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you would say "Oh wow" is a **favorite line** of his.

Answer (score 0):

"Hallmark," in that context conveys something unique and dignifiable.

"Bird call," might be slightly contemptuous instead.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Could you please provide references and/or citations to strengthen your answer? Feel free to visit our Help site on ["How do I write a good answer?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

How about *signature saying* or *signature phrase*?

For example, [here](http://www.newsmax.com/FastFeatures/barack-obama-signature/2014/11/24/id/609374/) are several *signature sayings/phrases* used by President Barack Obama:

> - “Let me be clear”
> - “Make no mistake”
> - “Here’s the deal”
> - “It will not be easy”

One could also call these *catch phrases*, but the addition of *signature* ties them to the person who uses them habitually.

OD:

> [*signature*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/signature):
>   a distinctive pattern, product, or characteristic by which someone or
>   something can be identified

Your example:

> My buddy Bill always exclaims “oh wow” whenever he is surprised. “Oh
>   wow” is a *signature saying/phase* of his.

Comment: I think mannerism is usually used to refer to movements or ways of speaking, not the specific words spoken.

Comment: @Barmar  Now that I think about it, and reread the definition, I think you're right. I'm going to delete. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest [Leitmotif](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/leitmotif)

***'Oh wow' is a leitmotif of his.***

Though it's more commonly used in terms of music but I think it can work in this situation. I came across [this site](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-English-equivalent-of-the-Hindi-Urdu-word-Takiya-Kalaam), it would be helpful too.